# Open sets for being generated by two topology.

Tags: general-topology

$(X,T_1 \cup T_2)$ for two topological sets $(X, T_1)$ and $(X,T_2)$

Since union of the topology sets not necessarily topological set, We can't say $(X,T_1 \cup T_2)$ is always topological space. So I add more condition that $(X,T_3)$ which is $T_3 = \langle T_1 \cup T_2 \rangle$ (I.e. $T_3$ is topology generated by the $T_1 \cup T_2$ )

So my question is like the below.

First, Does the $T_3$ have a sub-basis as open sets in $T_1$ or $T_2$?

(I.e. For $\forall G_3 \in T_3$, $\exists G_1(\in T_1)$ and $G_2(\in T_2)$ $s.t.$ '$G_1 \cap G_2 = G_3$' )

More simply speaking, I would suggest the statement. ($G_1, G_2$ is a open on $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively)

$(*)$ "Open set $G$ on the $\langle T_1 \cup T_2 \rangle$ $\iff$ $G$ is a open set on "$T_1$ **or** $T_2$" including the $G=G_1 \cap G_2$

[All the open sets in $T_1$ or $T_2$ are sub-basis of the $(X,\langle T_1 \cup T_2 \rangle)$
]

Second, Let's consider the closed set in $T_3$

Like the we did in first case, I would suggest the statement ($F_1, F_2$ is a closed on $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively)

$(**)$ "Closed set $F$ on the $\langle T_1 \cup T_2 \rangle$ $\iff$ $F$ is a closed set on $T_1$ **or** $T_2$" including $F=F_1 \cap F_2$

I'm not sure those statement is correct or not. If it is not true, Please suggest the counterexamples of those. Plus if it is not true, What is the form of the basis in $T_3$ ?

Any help and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the subbase $T_1\cup T_2$ generates the base consisting of all intersections of finitely many sets in $T_1\cup T_2$, and it’s not hard to prove that every such intersection is equal to one of the form $G_1\cap G_2$, where $G_1\in T_1$ and $G_2\in T_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal{T}_1 \cup \mathcal{T}_2$ forms a subbase for the smallest topology on $X$ that contains both $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$,denoted by $\mathcal{T}_1 \lor \mathcal{T}_2$ (the sup in the lattice of topologies).

A base for this topology is then given by $$\mathcal{B}:= \{O_1 \cap O_2: O_1 \in \mathcal{T}_, O_2 \in \mathcal{T}_2\}$$

$C$ is closed in this topology $\mathcal{T}_3 = \mathcal{T}_1 \lor \mathcal{T}_2$ iff $C$ is an intersection of a family sets of the form $F \cup G$, where $F$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $G$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_2$, by simple (de Morgan) duality considerations. *Not* the simple idea you propose.

As an illustrative example: let $\mathcal{T}_1$ be the right facing Sorgenfrey topology on $\Bbb R$ (base sets $[a,b)$) and $\mathcal{T}_2$ be its left facing variant (base sets $(a,b]$). Then $\mathcal{T}_3$ is discrete and $\Bbb Q$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_3$ while being dense (so "far from closed") in both $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ etc.